# Changing structure of array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am completely new to programming and was tasked with changing the structure of an array, I just can't get it to work.

This is the original array:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [att_values_id] => 5
        [att_value] => Sloping
        [att_id] => 5
        [att_category] => Frame
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [att_values_id] => 13
        [att_value] => Time Trial
        [att_id] => 5
        [att_category] => Frame
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [att_values_id] => 21
        [att_value] => Mountain
        [att_id] => 5
        [att_category] => Frame
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [att_values_id] => 15
        [att_value] => Carbon
        [att_id] => 3
        [att_category] => Material
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [att_values_id] => 15
        [att_value] => Titanium
        [att_id] => 9
        [att_category] => Frame
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [att_values_id] => 15
        [att_value] => Aluminum
        [att_id] => 17
        [att_category] => Frame
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [att_values_id] => 7
        [att_value] => Expensive
        [att_id] => 12
        [att_category] => Price
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [att_values_id] => 7
        [att_value] => Moderate
        [att_id] => 33
        [att_category] => Price
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [att_values_id] => 7
        [att_value] => Entry Level
        [att_id] => 40
        [att_category] => Price
    )
```

And I have to change it to this:

```
Array
   (
       [Frame] => Array
           (
                [5] => Sloping
                [13] => Mountain
                [21] => Time Trial
            )
       [Material] => Array
           (
                [3] => Carbon
                [9] => Titanium
                [17] => Aluminum
            )
       [Price] => Array
           (
                [12] => Expensive
                [33] => Moderate
                [40] => Entry Level
            )
      )
```

I have tried using foreach to go through the array but I don't know how to build the new array.

Comment: Not at all, I was put in a position at work where I am now in charge of implementing new functionality into our website, as I said I am new to programming and way too old to go to school for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this little pseudocode is the closest we can get before plainly doing your homework.

```
foreach (firstarray as key => value) {
 newarray[value['att_category']][value['att_id']]=value['att_value'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that Amenadiel, though I am not a student.